# Multi Layer Perceptron has low accuracy when it has 1 output neuron, works fine when it has more

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am makiing a Neural Network with an RBF hidden layer. First, the input goes into the RBF (trained with KMeans) and after that it goes to a Multi Layer Perceptron ( sklearn - python ) . The problem arises when I feed the MLP with my data from the RBF layer. If I try with e.g. (10, 2) layers I get something like 80% accuracy but when I try with (10, 1) I get around 50% accuracy.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from mlxtend.data import loadlocal_mnist
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
from random import sample
from math import sqrt
from time import time
import numpy as np

def convert(x):
    if x%2==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def calc_centers(x, k, n, algo='kmeans'):
    centers = list()
    if algo=='kmeans':
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0, precompute_distances=True, n_init=n).fit(x)
        centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    elif algo=='random':
        centers = sample(list(x), k)
    return centers

def phi(xi, xj, sigma):
    return np.e**(-1*distance(xi, xj)**2/(2*sigma**2))

def distance(x, y):
    d = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        d += (x[i]-y[i])**2
    d = sqrt(d)
    return d

def hidden_layer_output(xi, centers):
    k = len(centers)

    max_i = -1
    max_j = -1
    max_d = -1
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(i+1, k):
            dist = distance(centers[i], centers[j])
            if dist > max_d:
                max_d = dist
                max_i = i
                max_j = j

    sigma = max_d/sqrt(2*k)

    return [phi(xi, xj, sigma) for xj in centers]

def run(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, k, n, algo):
    #t=time()
    centers = calc_centers(x_train, k, n, algo)

    hidden_layer_outputs = list()

    for x in x_train:
        hidden_layer_outputs.append(hidden_layer_output(x, centers))

    neurons = (k, 2) # <----------------- THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION ----------------------->
    learning_rate = 0.001
    earlyStop = False
    model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=neurons, activation='relu',
                          max_iter = 2000, solver='adam', random_state=1,
                          learning_rate_init=learning_rate,
                          early_stopping=earlyStop)

    model.fit(hidden_layer_outputs, y_train)
    #Dt = '{0:.1f}'.format(time() - t)
    y1 = model.predict(hidden_layer_outputs)
    #y2 = model.predict([hidden_layer_output(x, centers) for x in x_test])

    #print(str(100*p)+'% variance level, '+str(neurons)+' neurons')
    #print('Learning rate: '+str(learning_rate))
    #print('Early Stopping: '+str(earlyStop))
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(100*metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y1))+'% training accuracy')
    #print('{0:.2f}'.format(100*metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y2))+'% testing accuracy')
```

And my main:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    (x_train, y_train) = loadlocal_mnist(
        images_path='train-images.idx3-ubyte',
        labels_path='train-labels.idx1-ubyte')
    (x_test, y_test) = loadlocal_mnist(
        images_path='t10k-images.idx3-ubyte',
        labels_path='t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte')

    x_train = np.array(x_train)[:2000]
    y_train = np.array(y_train)[:2000]
    x_test = np.array(x_test)[:2000]
    y_test = np.array(y_test)[:2000]

    k=20
    n=20
    sc = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
    x_train = sc.transform(x_train)
    x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

    p = 0.95
    pca = PCA(p)
    pca.fit(x_train)
    x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
    x_test = pca.transform(x_test)

    y_train = [convert(y) for y in y_train]
    y_test = [convert(y) for y in y_test]

    #run(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, k, n, 'kmeans')
    run(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, k, n, 'random')
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: i think you should also add what are you trying to learn here, in general i think what you said makes a lot of sense, a NN with only 1 hidden layer is a not a very deep one, meaning it cannot express as many functions as 2 layer NN would. also note that the amount of data should be considered when going to NN as a prediction model.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I am trying to predict if an MNIST handwritten digit is even or odd (that's why I have a convert() function for the y sets). The MLP has k input neurons and 1 or 2 output neurons, so I think there is margin for learning but I might as well be wrong here.